# Find the file containing 2 Pattern in TCL/TK

Tags: shell, scripting, tcl

`enter code here`I have a link in Linux
When I run tool for the fist time

```
/invcui.prects/report/prects.summary.gz
```

When I run for the second time

```
/invcui.prects/report/prects#1.summary.gz
```

And I want to set a for this Link

```
set input [open  "/invcui.prects/report/prects(.*).summary.gz" r]
```

But it's not working

I want to find the file containing 2 pattern `"prects" "summary.gz"` and set a equal it

Answer (score 1):

You want [the `glob` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm)

```
set files [glob -directory /invcui.prects/report prects*.summary.gz]
foreach file $files {...}
```

---

To specifically match the files with `#num`:

```
set files [glob -directory $dir prects.summary.gz prects#*.summary.gz]
```

Comment: what If has file prects_hold_hold.summary.gz?

Comment: how to not find pattern _hold_hold?

Comment: If you have additional requirements, please add them in the question not in comments.

Comment: Or ask another, more specific question. Linking to this one to say that you're asking what you think is a significant refinement of it is _great!_